# Does scaling LSTM weights makes sense?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, transfer

I want to transfer hidden states from multiple LSTM networks into new network. Does it make sense to have the hidden states scaled or standardized before I input them into the new network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly possible to ruin the network this way. Take a look at LSTM equations below:

[image: LSTM]

Depending on the input sequence `x`, scaling `Wi` or `Wc` can make the corresponding biases dominant, which will basically form a completely new network. The same input sequence `x` will result in different long- and short-term states, and there's no reason to think they are better. Scaling both weights and biases is also odd, because it changes the scale of the whole linear layer.

If you are interested in weight regularization, it's better to incorporate it into the original network, rather than patch the trained model.

Comment: Thank you! And hidden states should not be regularized because of tanh, right. They always stay within [-1,1]? I was wondering if I can transfer hidden states in that case.